# What does 1 and 2 mean in command line input/output redirection?

Tags: linux

```
foo >out 2>&1
foo 2>&1 >out
```

Is 1 the output and 0 the input like in C?

Comment: `stdin` is 0 in POSIX, not 1. 1 is `stdout`, 2 is `stderr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0,1 and 2 are standard file descriptors in *NIX systems.

`2>&1`       # Redirects stderr to stdout.

0 | Standard input |STDIN_FILENO |  stdin

1 | Standard output | STDOUT_FILENO | stdout

2 | Standard error  | STDERR_FILENO |stderr

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 refers to file handles and have the same meaning as file handles in C when using the system calls for low level file management.

File handles in Linux are small integer numbers, which are used to index a per-process `struct file *` table. Index 0 is assigned to the file handle of what is known as standard input, index 1 is assigned to standard output, and index 2 is assigned to standard error.